# What does that "level" mean in the "Initiate of Amaunator" feat spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms

Im playing as a paladin under the Risen Sun heresy.

As it says in the "Power of Faerun" book on page 58, I can use the "Initiate of Amaunator" feat, it gives me more spells to my paladin.

My doubt is: **What does that "level" that come together the spell means?**

It means my level, my spellcaster level, or the magic level (but on 3.5 the magic is up to level 4)?

Comment: We have [a policy of not linking to D&D tools or its mirrors](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2770/1204), given they are engaged in piracy. Please assume answerers legally own the book you refer to and can look up the material themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Level" on that chart refers to spell level, not caster level. Any benefit that says "...add to your spell list..." means that the spells indicated are added to the list of spells you can prepare or choose. Essentially, they become additional options as if they were Paladin spells, of the indicated level, that had always been available to you.

As a result, because Paladin spellcasting tops out at 4th level, you will never be able to cast *sunburst* or *time stop* because you will never have 8th or 9th level spell slots.

Comment: oh thanks, so i will never cast those spells.